# How do you construct a node map for pathfinding in a non-tiled 2D environment?

Tags: 2d, algorithm, ai, path-finding

A* and Dijkstra's pathfinding algorithms work by navigating a node map. In a tile-based 2D environment, these nodes could easily be inferred to be the literal `x,y` positions of the map.

For example, the agent is at `(0,0)`, an obstacle is at `(0,1)`, and the agent wants to go to `(0,2)`.

However, in a 2D environment where locations are represented using floating point variables `float x, float y`, agents and obstacles can exist between the traditional style nodes `(0,0)` and `(0,1)`.

How do you create a node map from such an environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two most common answers are to use waypoints or navigations meshes (navmeshes).

In the former case, you pick various points on your map, precompute which are "neighbors" (have a clear path between them), and explicitly link them together.

In the latter case, you generate a triangle mesh covering all walkable regions.  Your nodes can be triangles with graph-edges being the shared triangle-edges.  Or nodes could be midpoints of triangle-edges with the graph-edges being computed from the triangles.

Comment: This is GREAT information, thank you. The phrase "triangular navigation mesh" eventually led me to [this](http://graphics.ucmerced.edu/papers/10-mig-navq.pdf) rather educational paper *Navigational Queries on Triangular Meshes*. I feel much better equipped to approach this problem now.

Comment: Also, [this](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci777s2c/ijcai05.pdf#page=53) paper is great.

Comment: Also of note is the [funnel algorithm](http://digestingduck.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm.html)